# How to decompose this time-varying optimization problem (semidefinite program) in order to solve it?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, dynamic-programming, semidefinite-programming

Let us consider the following semidefinite program
\begin{align*}
&\min_{X_{t}, \Omega_t, \Pi} \quad \frac{1}{T+1} \sum_{t=0}^{T} \text{Tr} (X_t) \quad \text{s.t.}\\
&\begin{bmatrix} X_{t} & L_t \\ L_t^{\text{T}} & \Omega_{t} \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0, \;\; 0 \leq t\leq T,  \\
& \begin{bmatrix}
C_{t+1}^{\text{T}} \Pi C_{t+1} - \Omega_{t+1} + \Xi_{t}  & \Xi_{t} A_{t} \\
A_{t}^{\text{T}} \Xi_{t} & \Omega_{t} + A_{t}^{\text{T}} \Xi_{t} A_{t}
\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0,  0 \leq t \leq T-1,  \\
&\begin{bmatrix} I_{p_{i}}/\alpha_{i}^{2} + V_i^{-1} & E_{i}^\text{T}\\
E_{i} & V-V \Pi V
\end{bmatrix}\succeq0,\;\; 1 \leq i\leq n.  
\end{align*}
The third constraint contains variables that depend both on t and t+1 (t is the time). Does anyone know how to decompose this semidefinite program in order to solve the optimization problem efficiently from computational point of view please(interior-point methods, Lagrangian, primal-dual, dynamic programming etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "decompose", specifically. This is already an SDP as written, right?

Comment: Thank you Michael Grant. By decompose, I mean, how to decompose it in order to solve it efficiently from computational point of view.

Comment: Have you tried a standard modeling framework like YALMIP, CVX, cvxpy, Convex.jl, etc.?

Comment: We can not solve it actually with standard framework like YALMIP, CVX, etc.. We need to decompose it in order to solve it efficiently from computational point of view

Comment: I'm not seeing why that is. What are the various sizes here: what is T?

Comment: T is a fixed constant, but the semi-definite program is time varying and one constraint depends both on t (the time) and t+1. Yalmip cannot solve that.

Comment: I suspect that's just a challenge in formulation. I am certain that both CVX and YALMIP can handle it. Since you are already using the latter I suggest asking their user group.

Comment: Ok, we are required to find sophisticated
and efficient algorithms based on methods like the interior-point method for
SDP.  I will read more ask also the user group for YALMIP in order to know how they could solve it, thanks.